# Eclipse RCP: Extension Point (restorable="false") does not work on Stacked views

Tags: eclipse, view, eclipse-rcp, rcp, workbench

In the Extension Points, i define a vew NOT restorable.

```
    <view
            id="..."
            name="..."
            class="..."
            allowMultiple="true"
            restorable="false">
    </view>
```

All the views that are "stacked" (minimized) are NOT closed when the workbench closes. **Is this normal behavior?**

I have to manually close the views...

```
public static void hideViews(IWorkbenchPage page) {
    //list of views VISIBLE on this page
    IViewReference[] views=page.getViewReferences();
    for(int i=0; i<views.length; i++) {
        //hide view
    }
}
```

Thanks.

EDIT: I opened an eclipse BUG.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=358578